# docker-compose postgresql persitent local storage

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, persistent-storage

How can I setup postgresql in docker to be persistent into a local folder?

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6.1-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=a
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=a
      - POSTGRES_DB=a
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql:./postgres
volumes:
  pgdata:
    driver: local
```

This will not work and yield only

```
ERROR: for db  Cannot create container for service db: invalid volume spec "postgres": invalid volume specification: 'postgres': invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path: 'postgres' mount path must be absolute
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use absolute mount path, `./postgres` should be changed.

Comment: so it is not possible to mount to current sub directory?

Comment: it is but you are using it wrong. first part is host directory, the second part is containers. `./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql`